# Employee with Subordinate and Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select

I am using below query to select all employee info and their subordinates. I need to count total subordinate as well. But, I facing a problem where when the data size growth, more than 12k rows of data, the select statement become extremely slow. Anyone have any idea how to go about this?
Notes: empLogin and mgrLogin both are varchar(30)

```html
DECLARE @v_empLogin varchar(30) = 'Albert21';
WITH EmployeeList
 AS (SELECT  empLogin, empName ,mgrLogin
 ,departmentID,0 AS Level
  FROM   Employees 
  WHERE  mgrLogin  =@v_empLogin 
  and isActive =1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT usr.empLogin,usr.empName,usr. mgrLogin
  ,usr.departmentID, mgr.[Level] + 1
  FROM   Employees  AS usr
     INNER JOIN EmployeeList AS mgr ON usr. mgrLogin = mgr.empLogin 
  WHERE  usr.mgrLogin  IS NOT NULL
  AND usr.isActive=1 and usr.empLogin  
  )


SELECT u.empLogin , u.empName, u.mgrLogin
,u.departmentID, u.EmpLevel , mg.Total,u.isActive  
FROM   EmployeeList AS u
left JOIN (SELECT u.mgrLogin , COUNT(empLogin) as 'Total'
FROM   EmployeeList AS u group by u.mgrLogin )
mg on mg.mgrLogin  = u.empLogin
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MSSQL Relational db

Comment: What about showing the structure of your table as well as of the desired result? That would certainly help us help you.